# Getting the remainder of a round

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rounding

I have a use case where I have a column in `MySQL` which contains a number such as `12.458`.

I need to get a listing of these numbers AND they need to be updated in the database so that they are rounded to two decimal places, I realize it will still store the 3 decimal places in the database, but I mean so like the example I gave is rounded to `12.460`.

I know I could just easily do this via MySQL and then get the data with a following query no problems; however I don't want to do that in-case the data is updated within the time it gets rounded and the time I actually select it.

So what I thought if doing was just selecting it and THEN rounding it with PHP such as..

```
$amount = round($amount, 2);
```

...and yes, the data now could have changed in the database again since I selected it; but that's not the important part - the important part is running a `-` or `+` operation on the amount in the database.

So what I'm wanting to do is basically get the remaining result of the round and then run an operation on the mysql field..

So...

```
12.457 = 12.46 = +0.003 to field
12.421 = 12.42 = -0.001 to field
```

Unfortunately the table is not InnoDB and I cannot lock it from updates.

Is there a better way to do what I want?

**Edit:** Can you do a `SELECT` and `UPDATE` at the same time so you get the updated data from the select?

Comment: Can you please explain again why not do that while inserting? Or just inside the DB?

Comment: @NoyGabay I'm not sure what you mean sorry.

Comment: Why not do that update inside the db?

Comment: @NoyGabay Because by the time I run the select the values may of been changed by another update to them.

Comment: can't you just do: `SELECT ROUND(amount,2) AS roundedAmount, amount, ROUND(amount,2) - amount AS amountDiff` ?

Comment: Having such discrepancy between the data and the code is bad design. I'd advise having one update to the code during a scheduled maintenance window (you can even write a query to update the rows one by one, rendering a collision unlikely), and then just make sure you insert the data using the correct format.

Comment: @StevieG No because the data in the database needs to be updated as well at the same time.

Comment: @NoyGabay I don't think you understand. I need to make the UPDATE before I select the data.

Comment: UPDATE and SELECT are two different operations. Best you can do is [chain](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) them. I am still not seeing the need though..

Comment: @Brett - Update it then.. `UPDATE table SET diff_col = ROUND(amount,2) - amount`..?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
    (`ExistingValue` decimal(12,3), `ExtraValue` decimal(12,3))
;

INSERT INTO YourTable
    (`ExistingValue`, `ExtraValue`)
VALUES
    (12.458, null)
;

update YourTable
set
  ExtraValue = ExistingValue - Round(ExistingValue,2)
, ExistingValue = Round(ExistingValue,2)
;
select
*
from YourTable

| EXISTINGVALUE | EXTRAVALUE |
|---------------|------------|
|         12.46 |     -0.002 |
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c6ca/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If your primary concern is seeing outdated values then you can use a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html):

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE yourTable SET  yourField = round(yourField, 2);
SELECT * FROM yourTable;
COMMIT;
```

Even if other processes update the table you will see consistent results. This relies on InnoDB however.